# Only Firefox diplays Logo at middle no matter how much zoom. IE and Chrome don't read top and bottom margins. Anyone knows why?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The following CSS showld put the logo right in the middle as the margins are pushed by the same value from both left and right, and top and bottom, however, this happens only on firefox for some reason that I obviously don't have a clue of.

```
body {
    background-image:url(Background.png);
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
   } /*backgroung*/






.logo {
        left:0;
        top:0px;
        right:0;
        bottom:0px;
        position:absolute;
        min-width:444px;
        margin: 230px; 400px;
        text-align:center;
    } /*logo positioning*/




    .logo {
        background-image:url(Logo.png);
        background-position:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    } /*logo image*/




    .logo:hover {
        background-image:url(Logo2.png);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center;
    } /*mouseover*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a link we can check?

Try using “padding-top: 150px”. It usually works unless there is something that is keeping you from doing it. Or, try the regular trick “ zoom: 1”,”position: relative”, “display: block”.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in your css try to add height. that should fix the issue.

```
.logo {
        left:0;
        top:0px;
        right:0;
        bottom:0px;
        position:absolute;
        min-width:444px;


        min-height:some xyz px;


        margin: 230px; 400px;
        text-align:center;
    } /*logo positioning*/
```

I have included another div and created [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEQjjy).

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML as follows, and I am also posting the full CSS. The social icons I put in (facebook and twitter) respond perfectly in any browser. The logo's margins seem to be cut as I indicate in the CSS only if read with firefox. I have tried to specify the height but had the issue anyway.
If you know any trick that will work in any browser just explain me because I've been around CSS and HTML only for a week, so I know the normal commands but don't know many tricks, so I'd love to understand those tricks and why they work rather than normal css attributes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>LoD</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Favicon.ico" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container"> 
        <a href="Index.html" /><img class="logo" />

        <ul id="social">
        <li class="facebook";><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Albus.Severus.Vitanza" target="_blank"><img src="Facebook4.png" style="width:80px; height:73px;" onmouseover="this.src='Facebook2.png';" onmouseout="this.src='Facebook4.png';"/></a></li>
        <li class="twitter";><a href="https://twitter.com/Promoetheus" target="_blank"><img src="Twitter.png" style="width:80px; height:73px;"  onmouseover="this.src='Twitter2.png'"; onmouseout="this.src='Twitter.png';"/></a></li>
        <li class="plot";><img src="Plot.png" style="width:140px; height:73px" onmouseover="this.src='Plot3.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Plot.png'" onclick="this.src='Plot2.png'" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--closes container-->


    <footer id="copyright">
        <p>© Giorgio Vitanza</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it! Apparently margin: [value in pixels] [value in pixels], with no ";" in between, fixed the issue in any browser. Strange but true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is now, that when I zoom down the pic doesn't hold its central position.